# Pass Data from last ViewController to root ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 3 ViewControllers, A, B and C.
My navigation stack is like A -> B and B-> C. Now I want to pass data back to controller A from Controller C.
Is there any way to send data directly from ViewController C to ViewController A?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Notification Center. Or else find the view controller from navigation stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @ElTomato I have a stack of multiple ViewControllers

Comment: @RajaKishan Notification Center worked for me

Comment: Feel free to run a search and find a topic that could answer your question. @FahadNazir

Comment: Use NotificationCenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For navigation stack , Your scenario is A->B->C so stack is [A,B,C] . You can reach expected ViewController with using

```
 let viewControllerA = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0] as! AViewController // 0 is viewcontroller index which in stack.
```

then when you want to send data to this vc or changing some data in this vc you can reach it with

```
viewControllerA.changingVariable = "bla bla"
```